# Exporting data into Excel file using PHP

Tags: php, excel

My problem looks like this at the front side:

[image]

After choosing which of my users I want to export: 
[image]

I'm sending `AJAX` request containing their database `ids` to external file named `exportUsers.php`.

So this is how back end of my problem looks like:

When data arrive to `exportUsers.php`, I query the database and make array(`$data`) like this, which I want to export into `Excel` file.

[image]

This is how i tried to trigger download:

```
function cleanData(&$str)
    {
        $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
        if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    }
$flag = false;
foreach($data as $row1) {
    if(!$flag) {
        // display field/column names as first row
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($row1)) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
        }
    array_walk($row, __NAMESPACE__ . '\cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row1)) . "\r\n";
   }
$filename = "users_data" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
```

But this is all I see in Network tool of my browser:
[image]
But no download was triggered. Please help

Comment: Make sure that no character is sent to the browser before the header() directives (a space, a carriage return, an UTF8 BOM marker, etc.)

Comment: How to check what is sent first?

Comment: An ajax call won't automatically trigger a download, becaue by using Ajax you're basically telling the browser that you're going to override its normal behaviour and handle it within your own js code in the success block.... so you're getting the data sent correctly, but not actually handling it

Comment: @Mark Baker yeah, i thought it is due to ajax. But now i tried to do it with `$.post` but nothing was downloaded. Do you have idea how to send those ids that i need to handle if no ajax nor $.post works?

Comment: Well the easiest way is probably to simply issue a standard request targetted at blank, rather than using ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 session_start();
 include "connection.php";


$sql= mysql_query("select * from table") or die(print "Failed Download :".mysql_error());
$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);
// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
$output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
}
$output .="\n";
}

// Download the file

$filename = "FileName.xls";
header('Content-type: application/xls');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;

//jzend... 
exit;


?>
```